# flex popup that stays inside a container

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I retrieved a fine component for drawing in flex. It uses some floating toolpalette like:

```
toolBox = PopUpManager.createPopUp( this, ToolPalette ) as ToolPalette;
```

I tried to integrate that component into a new flex MXML component like a tileWindow: 
Works fine except that these tools palette are OUTSIDE the component.

Is there a way to constrain the toolBox created with `PopupManager` to stay within its parent container ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used createPopUp when the popup component was "titleWindow". But when I want a Canvas component added in the popup, I created a titleWindow and added the Canvas component as a child to the TitleWindow.

```
var titleWindow:TitleWindow;
titleWindow=new ResizableTitleWindow();
titleWindow.showCloseButton=true;
//Canvas Component
var toolPalette:ToolPalette=new ToolPalette();
// Add the Canvas component to the Titlewindow
titleWindow.addChild(toolPalette);              
PopUpManager.addPopUp(titleWindow, this, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the modal property when you call the createPopup method to true.

```
createPopUp(this, toolPalette, true, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

By deffinition on adobes site no you can not constrain

> createPopUp -- Creates a top-level
>   window and places it above other
>   windows in the z-order.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#addPopUp%28%29

Thats' not saying you couldn't try to create a mask of some sort